# Massive latency with xrdp over LAN

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, xrdp, rdp

I recently setup a VM running Ubuntu 18.10 and installed xrdp so that I can connect to it from my Windows machine running on the same network. I am connecting using the built-in Windows RDP client and I am experiencing what feels like a second or so latency and an awful frame rate. I have tested the connection speed between the two machines using iperf and received this result:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
    Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local 10.172.214.165 port 5001 connected with 10.172.152.25 port 49993
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec   895 MBytes   750 Mbits/sec
[  4] local 10.172.214.165 port 5001 connected with 10.172.152.25 port 50037
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec   748 MBytes   627 Mbits/sec
[  4] local 10.172.214.165 port 5001 connected with 10.172.152.25 port 50050
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec   910 MBytes   763 Mbits/sec
```

So I am fairly confident the network is not the issue. I also connect to a Windows box on the same hypervisor with no issues.

I have tried using a lower colour depth but this has not had any noticeable impact on performance and I am at a loss for what could still be causing this issue